# Read MacOs Notifications while screen is locked AppleScript

Tags: macos, automation, notifications, applescript

I have managed to put together an **AppleScript** that **reads** the **notifications** and outputs the text of these. While it **works while the display is on and unlocked**, I **haven't** been able to read the notifications **while on the lock screen**.

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
on run
    delay 6.0 -- wait for locking the screen
    tell application "System Events"
        try
            set _groups to groups of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window "Notification Center" of application process "NotificationCenter"
            repeat with _group in _groups
                return the value of static text 1 of _group --limit to one notification for the moment
            end repeat
        end try
    end tell
end run
```

This is my current code, which **successfully reads the notification** title of the most recent notification on **macOS Ventura**. However, after locking the screen (⌘ + Ctrl + Q) and trying to read the notification, the code **doesn't output anything**, even though the notification is **still visible** in the same location.

### *Final Goal:*

To execute this script (with the required error handling) every 10 seconds, even when the display is locked, and for it to read the notification to pass it on to a different script.

---

*If there is any other way to read macOS notifications through a script, they're also welcomed.*

Comment: @Philippe, while that could help in choosing how to read the notification depending on whether the screen is locked, it doesn't help with reading the notification contents when it's locked.

Comment: If you add it as an answer I’d be happy to mark it as accepted. @Philippe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a python script with which you can get notification contents:

```
https://github.com/ydkhatri/MacForensics/blob/master/macNotifications.py
```